# problem of installing Elgg on IIS web Server

Tags: elgg

I am installing Elgg on IIS web server and I got this problem:

```
Web server

We think your server is running the IIS web server.

The rewrite rules test failed. You need to configure your web server with Elgg's rewrite rules and try again.
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elgg officially only supports use on an Apache server.  See [here](http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Installation/Requirements)

That being said, people have [made it work](http://community.elgg.org/pg/forum/topic/486696/elgg-on-iis-7/), and there's an [Elgg doc](http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Elgg_and_IIS) on the issues involved in running Elgg on an IIS server.

In general, a good place to start for inquiries like this is the [main Elgg technical docs](http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Main_Page).

Best,
Mike